# How can I delay loading of a launchd Launch Daemon on boot?

Tags: macports, apache, launchd

I am running OS X Server 10.7.5 on a Mac Mini and I cannot get MacPorts’ Apache2 to start on boot. I have ensured that the Apple-supplied version of Apache is not launching and I have also ensured that the MacPorts-supplied apache2 LaunchDaemon is loading, it just isn’t actually starting Apache.

I say that the LaunchDaemon is loading because after boot when Apache is not running I get this:

```
% sudo port load apache2
org.macports.apache2: Already loaded
```

Then if I do the following Apache2 will start

```
% sudo port unload apache2
% sudo port load apache2
```

Because the machine also runs OS X Server’s DNS server with an internal-only domain name I am starting to think that the MacPorts Apache2 LaunchDaemon is attempting to run before the DNS is fully up and responding correctly thus causing Apache to think there is a servername mismatch and thus failing to actually start Apache.

I would like to find a way to delay the loading of the MacPorts Apache2 LaunchDaemon in order to give a little more time for DNS to be ready to see if this is indeed the problem.

Is there a way to add some sort of delay to that LaunchDaemon or somehow tell the system to wait a little longer before loading it?

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried this solution already? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2380304

Comment: The answer Mark Wilson selected? It isn’t actually a solution, just an explanation, but that explanation is exactly what led me to believe the problem is with DNS not being “ready.”